# Duplicated id's inside and outside noscript

Tags: html, validation

Wondering if an id within a noscript element should collide with the same id outside the noscript element.

Consider this:

```
<noscript>
  <div id="foo">...</div>
</noscript>

<div id="foo">...</div> // added with javascript
```

I can't find a good source that says what the content inside the noscript element really is. An unofficial source says its plain text / string (while scripts are allowed / active).
When inspecting the markup in firefox devtools, the code inside the noscript element looks like raw text / string. So I'm thinking it might be just plain text, but some tools / validators throws an error for duplicate id's.

Tools that consider it to be an error:

- Siteimprove
- W3C markup validation

Tools that doesn't consider it an error:

- Accessibility Insights for web
- Axe
- Wave
- ARC

I will probably change one of the the id's to be safe.
But I'm interested to know what is correct. Since we get different results in some commonly used tools.

Edit:
The outer div#foo is added by script, so if scripts are disabled, the outer div won't be there. So the question about this "collision" only applies to this state, when the noscript content isn't rendered.

Comment: Duplicate ids are always an issue no matter where they are. The ID has to be unique for the entire document not just parts of it. The only reliable tool to see if a markup is valid or not is W3C.

Comment: Absolutely! But if the contents of noscript is plain text, then Siteimprove and W3Cs validator are doing something wrong in their way of looking for duplicates. Or its more complicated than that. Either way, I'd like to know the details of why they deem it an error.

Comment: Even if they are in a `noscript` tag they remain part of the document and the DOM. Besides `noscript` is nothing to hide an element normally, it is "just" a fallback-

Comment: I'lll mark your first comment as a correct answer. Since I do believe you are right regarding W3C being most reliable. But I'm still curious as to why they won't allow it, IF its plain text.

Comment: Do you have any supplementary questions concerning _accessibility_, since you used that tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The HTML Standard specifies](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-noscript-element) that the `<noscript>` elements are [**transparent**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#transparent) in terms of their content model, *when scripting is disabled*.

> […] The content model of a transparent element is derived from the content model of its parent element: the elements required in the part of the content model that is "transparent" are the same elements as required in the part of the content model of the parent of the transparent element in which the transparent element finds itself.

So it still provides part of the DOM, it is *not* [Text content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#text-content)—except for if it is used inside e.g. `<textarea>`, which has such content model.

When scripts are disabled, the rules for `id` generally apply for its contents as well.

When scripts are disabled, the structured content of the `<noscript>` elements will be integrated into the DOM, and any duplicate ids will collide.

> The `noscript` element represents nothing if scripting is enabled, and represents its children if scripting is disabled.

When scripts are enabled, it’s not text content either, the HTML standard defines it as *nothing*.

If the element with the ID is generated by a script, you cannot have a collision with *nothing*, and you can probably ignore the error.

It’s correct if validators are reporting this as an error, as they only receive the generated HTML and cannot determine that a script generated that element.

Comment: Gotcha. In this case, the other div would not be there if scripts were disabled. But this clears things up.

Comment: So the div#foo outside the noscript is dynamically added by a script? I didn’t notice that in your question. Then your question becomes tricky. I believe you can ignore the error then.

Comment: Yeah I did not mention that sorry. Okay now Im back to confused. There will not be a collision between a normal element with id foo and a "transparent" element with the same id?

Comment: Edited the question. So either I don't truly understand transparent elements or W3C is doing something wrong when validating this. Or both.

Comment: I tried to clarify that in my answer. There will be a collision if the element is in the HTML delivered from the server. If it’s in the DOM because a script added it, there _cannot_ be a collision. The W3C validator cannot know which is the case, so it needs to report an error. Is that helping?

Comment: Yeah that sounds about right, thanks! Ended up changing the IDs in the noscript part, just to be safe